# Border IsMouseOver Trigger not working

Tags: wpf, triggers, effects

I have a problem with a `Trigger` and the property `IsMouseOver` in the following snippet

```
<Border Name="PART_Logo" Background="{DynamicResource Accent}" Width="36" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,76,0">
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="presentation:Commands.LogoClickCommand" Gesture="LeftClick" />
    </Border.InputBindings>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="3" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Logo}" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="3" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
        <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="presentation:Commands.LogoClickCommand" Gesture="LeftClick" />
        </Image.InputBindings>
    </Image>
</Border>
```

It just works on the bottom half of the `Border` here are two images which show the behavior:

[image: This works]
[image: This doesn't work]

Answer (score 1):

You have set Background directly on your border. Remove that and try setting the border inside the style

```
<Border.Style>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Accent}">
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="3" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you remove Border.InputBindings and Image.InputBindings

Please remove the following code, hopefully it would work.

```
<Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="presentation:Commands.LogoClickCommand" Gesture="LeftClick" />
</Border.InputBindings>

<Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="presentation:Commands.LogoClickCommand" Gesture="LeftClick" />
</Image.InputBindings>
```